# fit_generator expecting input for all layers of neural network?

Tags: python, keras

Newish to Keras and constructing a neural net with two dense layers. There's too much data to hold in memory, so I'm using the fit_generator function, but get the error `ValueError: No data provided for "dense_2". Need data for each key in: ['dense_2']`. Small example below:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
import numpy as np

model = Sequential([
    Dense(100, input_shape=(1924800,), activation='relu'),
    Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
])

model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

def generate_arrays_from_files(path, batch_size=50):
    while True:
        # Do things....
        yield ({'dense_1_input': np.asarray(outdata)}, {'output': np.asarray(outlabels)})

model.fit_generator(generate_arrays_from_files(path), steps_per_epoch=5, epochs=10)
```

Edit: forgot the compile line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to specify the layer in the input, and you obviously won't need to pass data to the second dense layer. Note that it's better to use a Keras generator, you can create a custom one like [this](https://stanford.edu/~shervine/blog/keras-how-to-generate-data-on-the-fly) or [use a standard one](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/).

You also need to compile your model.

```py
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
import numpy as np

model = Sequential([
    Dense(100, input_shape=(1924800,), activation='relu'),
    Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
])

optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=1e-3)
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer=optimizer,
              metrics=['accuracy'])

def generate_arrays_from_files(path, batch_size=50):
    while True:
        # Do things....
        yield np.asarray(outdata), np.asarray(outlabels)

model.fit_generator(generate_arrays_from_files(path), steps_per_epoch=5, epochs=10)
```

Is it normal to feed a vector of `(1924800,)` to the model by the way?

Comment: I had a compile line, just missed it in the copy-paste. For the data I'm dealing with, each data point is in fact `(1924800,)`. Removing the dictionary labels appears to have fixed the problem - I was working off of the example posted at [link](keras.io). Thanks!